# Previous button clearing all data from my fields in android activity

Tags: android, button, back

i am developing an android application. i have 8 activities in the application. i have a submit button in the last activity. the user can go back to any activity and edit the data before pressing submit.i have two buttons in every activity named as Next and previous. and in the last activity an extra button called Submit is there. I want to come to any previous page from the next page and edit the data and go to submit.

Now my problem is, every time i press Previous my previous-activity data fields are becoming blank..

please help me solving this problem.

Comment: can you post some code ?

Comment: you might destroying the previous activities while going to next activity. better you make your previous activities in onPause state. and destroy activity when you are pressing back button.

Comment: @shubha.. Exaclty what you want??? If after pressing back button , data is cleared then you have set use savedinstance state..

Answer (score 0):

Save the state of your activities with bundles. The back button ends the lifecycle of an activity. Here's a link that would guide you through what you should do. Hope this helps.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score 0):

Dont kill your activity while moving to other activity. Also you can set a flag while launching activity whihc will just put your activity to backstack and will be retrieved when relaunch by pressing back. Follow below link for details:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the state of Activity:

```
private static final String INPUT1 = "ip1";
private static final String INPUT2 = "ip2";

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putString(INPUT1, mEditText1.getText().toString());
    savedInstanceState.putString(INPUT2, mEditText2.getText().toString());

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

And restore it when Activity starts:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Always call the superclass first

    mEditText1 = findViewById(.....
    mEditText2 = findViewById(.....              

    // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        mEditText1.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(INPUT1));
        mEditText2.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(INPUT2));
    }

}
```

Also, you can tell `EditText` and other such Views to save their state individually, by adding `android:saveEnabled="true"` to their layout:

```
 <EditText
 android:id="@android:id/text1"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:saveEnabled="true"
 android:inputType="text"/>
```

Comment: Hey if u are declaring "INPUT 1" and "INPUT 2" as String then why using "put Int" and "get Int" instead of "put String" and "get String"?

Comment: i have two buttons in every activity named as Next and previous. and in the last activity an extra button called Submit is there. I want to come to any previous page from the next page and edit the data and go to submit. But every time i press Previous my previous-activity data fields are becoming blank..

Comment: [see link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)....